# Haskell infinite list with alternating signs

Tags: list, haskell, infinite

I try to generate a infinite list like this:

```
[1,-2,3,-4..]
```

with this code:

```
[ m  | n <- [1..],m <- [n, -n]]
```

but this code reduplicate all numbers like this:

```
[1,-1,2,-2..]
```

So i dont know what to do

Comment: Maybe think of how you can turn `[1..]` into your list just one element at a time. What do all the negative numbers have in common?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can group these as follows:

```
[[1, -2], [3, -4],..]
```

So we make tuples of `i` where `i` makes hops of two, and for such `i`, we yield `i` and `-i-1`:

```
[ m  | n <- [1,3..], m <- [n, -n-1]]
```

then for example we can yield:

```
Prelude> take 10 [ m  | n <- [1,3..], m <- [n, -n-1]]
[1,-2,3,-4,5,-6,7,-8,9,-10]
```

Or we can write it as:

```
[1, 3..] >>= \i -> [i, -i-1]
```

We can also work with `zipWith`:

```
zipWith (*) [1..] $ cycle [1, -1]
```

Or a solution where we iterate over functions:

```
zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate]) [1..]
```

Comment: `replicate [1, -1]`? Don't you mean `cycle [1, -1]`? By the way, I prefer `zipWith ($) (cycle [id, negate]) [1..]`, but that's personal preference.

Comment: @Zeta: lol, the edit and comment are almost exactly at the same time, what are the odds of a character-equivalent answer :).

Answer (score 1):

A possibility:

```
> x = concatMap (\i -> [i,-i-1]) [i | i <- [0..], even i]
> take 10 x
[0,-1,2,-3,4,-5,6,-7,8,-9]
```